# Exporting map series to TIFF using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, geotiff-tiff, arcgis-pro, map-series

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("LYTNAME")[0]
if not lyt.mapSeries is None:   
   ms = lyt.mapSeries   
   if ms.enabled:     
              pageName = lyt.mapSeries.pageRow.NOMENKLA
lyt.exportToTIFF(r"EXPRTPTH" + pageName, resolution=300, tiff_compression = "NONE")
```

Script exports one page with LZW compression.

How do I set it up so it exports all map series pages with no compression?